# How to solve $y''-4y'+5y=e^{2x}$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Could somebody explain in detail the steps required to solve this problem?

Comment: 1. Solve the homogenous equation $y’’-4y’+5y=0$. Denote the general solution by $y_c$.      2. Find a particular solution $y_p$ to $y’’-4y’+5y=e^{2x}$.      3. The general solution is $y_p+Cy_c,\forall C\in\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to solve the characteristic equation $m^2-4m+5=0$, obtaining $m=2 \pm i$. Then, the solution of the homogeneous equation $y''-4y'+5y=0$ is $y_h=c_1e^{(2+i)x}+c_2e^{(2-i)x}$, where $c_1, c_2 \in \mathbb{R}$. Applying Euler's Fórmula yields $$e^{2x}(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))+e^{2i}(\cos(x)-i\sin(x))=(c_2+c_1)e^{2x}\cos(x)+i(c_1-c_2)e^{2x}\sin(x).$$ Setting $A:=c_1+c_2$ and $B:=i(c_1-c_2)$ we get that $y_h=Ae^{2x}\cos(x)+Be^{2x}\sin(x)$, with $A,B \in \mathbb{C}$.

Now, we need to find a particular solution $y_p$ of the equation $y''-4y'+5y=e^{2x}$. There are two main ways: Using indetermined coeficints and variation of parameters.

- **Indetermined coeficients:** We know that a particular solution to the equation is of the form $y_p=ae^{2x}$, where $a$ is a constant. Plugging $y_p$ in the equation gives $$[ae^{2x}]''-4[ae^{2x}]'+5[ae^{2x}]=e^{2x} \Leftrightarrow 4ae^{2x}-8ae^{2x}+5ae^{2x}=e^{2x} \Leftrightarrow  ae^{2x}=e^{2x}$$ and therefore $a=1$. The general solution of the equation is $$y=y_h+y_p=Ae^{2x}\cos(x)+Be^{2x}\sin(x)+e^{2x}.$$

-**Variation of parameters:** Let $f$ be the function on the right hand-side of the equation, in this case $f(x)=e^{2x}$. In this case the two basis solutions are $y_1=e^{2x}\cos(x)$ and $y_2=e^{2x}\sin(x)$. And so the Wronskian is $$w(x)=\begin{vmatrix} 
e^{2x} \cos(x) & e^{2x}\sin(x)\\
[e^{2x}\cos(x)]' & [e^{2x}\sin(x)]'
\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix} 
e^{2x}\cos(x) & e^{2x}\sin(x)\\
2e^{2x}\cos(x)-e^{2x}\sin(x) & e^{2x}\cos(x)+2e^{2x}\sin(x)
\end{vmatrix},$$ hence $w(x)=e^{4x}$. Now, let $$v_1(x):=-\int \frac{y_{b_1}(x)f(x)}{w(x)}dx=-\int \frac{4x\sin(x)}{e^{4x}}dx=-\int \sin(x)dx=\cos(x)+C_1$$ and $$v_2(x):=\int \frac{y_{b_2}(x)f(x)}{w(x)}dx=\int \cos(x)dx=\sin(x)+C_2.$$ The particular solution is $$y_p=v_1(x)y_{b_1}(x)+v_2(x)y_{b_2}(x)=e^{2x}[\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)]=e^{2x}.$$ Hence the general solution of the equation is again $$y=y_h+y_p=Ae^{2x}\cos(x)+Be^{2x}\sin(x)+e^{2x}.$$

Answer (score 2):

**hint**: Write it as $(y''- 5y') + (y' -5y) = e^{2x}$. This prompts you to let $u = y' - 5y$. So $u' - u =e^{2x}$, and this means $(e^{-x}u)' = e^x$. So:  $e^{-x}u = e^x+C$, and $u = e^{2x} + Ce^x$. Repeat this trick for $y$ and get the answer. 
**note**: I infact solved a different question, but it shows you some trick to handle a similar situation..

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

You could have simplified the problem using $y=u\,e^{2x}$ making the equation to become $$u''+u=1$$

Answer (score 0):

We shall solve the equation over $C^2(\mathbb R)$. First, we would like to solve the homogenous equation 
$$y’’-4y’+5y=0$$
consider the auxiliary equation 
$$m^2-4m+5=0$$ 
This has the solutions $m=2\pm i$, this is to say, the general solution of the homogenous equation, $y_c$, is
$$y_c=e^{2x}(C_1\sin x+C_2\cos x)$$ where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are arbitrary real constants.

Now, when we look at the equation
$$y’’-4y’+5y=e^{2x}$$
We found that one of the particular solution may be in the form $y_p=ae^{2x}$, pitting this into the equation, we found that,
$$a(4e^{2x}-8e^{2x}+5e^{2x})=e^{2x}$$
$$a=1$$
Hence $y_p=e^{2x}$ is a particular solution. Now, since the difference between any two particular solutions must be a solution to the homogenous equation, we have
$$y=e^{2x}(b_1\sin x+b_2\cos x+1)$$
To be the general solution, where $b_1,b_2$ are arbitrary real constants.